# CSS: Horizontal Tabs Displaying Vertically in IE6 and Firefox

Tags: html, css, tabs

I have some CSS and HTML for horizontal tabs that works perfectly in jsfiddle.  However, in both Firefox 13 and IE6 (the browser I most need this to work in) the tabs are displayed as a vertical unordered list.

Here is the CSS:

```
.tablist
{
    list-style:none; 
    height:2em;
    padding:0; 
    margin:0; 
    border: none;
}
.tablist li
{
    display:inline-block;
    float: left;
}

.tablist li a
{
    float: left;
    margin-right:0.13em; 
    padding:0 1em;
    text-decoration:none;
    border:0.06em solid #000;
    border-bottom:0;
    font:bold 0.88em/2em arial,geneva,helvetica,sans-serif;
    color:#000;
    background-color:#ccc;

    /* CSS 3 elements */
    webkit-border-top-right-radius:0.50em;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius:0.50em;
    -moz-border-radius-topright:0.50em;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft:0.50em;
    border-top-right-radius:0.50em;
    border-top-left-radius:0.50em;
}

.tablist li a:hover
{
    background:#3cf; 
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.tablist li#current a
{
    background-color: #777;
    color: #fff;
}
.tablist li#current a:hover
{
    background: #39C;
}
```

And here is the HTML:

```
<div class="tablist">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#Dashboard"><strong>Tutorialsphere</strong></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><strong>Photoshop</strong></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><strong>Illustrator</strong></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><strong>Fireworks</strong></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><strong>Flash</strong></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><strong>CSS</strong></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><strong>PHP</strong></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

For a while this **was** working in Firefox and I don't remember changing anything -- but I must have.

Any advice is appreciated.

Regards.

Comment: You should provide the jsfiddle link

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/8YX7M/ In firefox 13.0.1/mac it works perfectly.

Comment: Darn it.  I'm using 13.0.1 on a Windows laptop.  It should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have IE6 handy, but try display: block; float:left to this selector: .tablist li a

Comment: Thanks.  It's displaying in IE6 now but still not in FF 13.  Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: I wonder what my problem is.  I get a vertical unordered list.

Comment: Sorry, it works like a charm!  I had forgotten to switch back to my original HTML after trying something else.  Thanks a million!  What change did you make?

Answer (score 1):

IE6 doesn't support inline-block.  As such, it's just ignoring your display property and leaving it at its default.